# count consecutive number of 10 days when number is = 0 or > 10

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is sqlfiddle that i made with mysql query
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2794/4

It count 10 consecutive days when present = 0, but i need to add second condition to count where present is > 10.

For example

11
22
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1

should count 14

here is that query

```
select sum(count) total from (

SELECT COUNT(present) as count FROM (
SELECT
IF((q.present != 0), @rownum:=@rownum+1, @rownum:=@rownum) AS rownumber, @prevDate:=q.date, q.*
FROM (
SELECT
name
, date
, present
FROM
teacher, (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prevDate:='') vars
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31'
ORDER BY date, present
) q
) sq
GROUP BY present, rownumber
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10

) d
```

So if U can help me, pls do it :)

best regards
m.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your query overly well, but I think simply changing (q.Present != 0) to incorporate the additional test should solve your problem:

```
SELECT sum(count) total from (
  SELECT COUNT(present) as count FROM (
    SELECT
      IF((q.present != 0 AND q.present <= 10), @rownum:=@rownum+1, @rownum:=@rownum) AS rownumber, @prevDate:=q.date, q.*
    FROM (
      SELECT
        name
        , date
        , present
      FROM
        teacher, (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prevDate:='') vars
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31'
      ORDER BY date, present
    ) q
  ) sq
  GROUP BY present, rownumber
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
) d
```

Comment: hey, thanks for try but it doesnt work, try this query on sqlfiddle and You'll see that nothing happend and there no count 14 days. So i need to try another query.